# Where can I find Intel documents on the assembly code generated by ICC in order to understand some keywords in it?

Tags: assembly, intel, icc

The following is an example of the assembly code I'm working on. I'm using Intel ICC 13.1.0. I wonder where can I find documents about it in order to understand some keywords like 'Latency' accurately.

```
    ..B10.21:                       # Preds ..B10.20 ..B10.12       # Infreq Latency 9
    incq      %r8                                           #206.2 c1
    vprefetch1 256(%rcx)                                    #206.2 c1
    addq      $64, %rax                                     #206.2 c5
    vprefetch0 128(%rcx)                                    #206.2 c5
    cmpq      %r13, %r8                                     #206.2 c9
    jl        ..B10.12      # Prob 82%                      #206.2 c9
                            # LOE rax rbx r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 zmm0 zmm1 k1
```

Comment: The word latency appears in a comment and isn't part of the program. You can find a definition of latency in the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual, but it may not mean exactly the same thing as the comment. Otherwise the assembly seems to be using the AT&T dialect which isn't properly documented anywhere.

Comment: There's a lot of links on this page, I know one of them answers your question, but they're all worth looking at. And I don't recall which link. Also, one of them goes to the actaul x86-32/64 assembly/machine guide (I have a hardcopy of it, but teh pdf is good, even has bookmarks) https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links.